# Two spinner issue

Tags: android, spinner

I'm trying to use two spinners at the same time but to no avail. I've created two spinners and used the if statement to differentiate the two.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.om, 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource
    (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.om2, 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource
    (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
    ()

    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
        position, long id) {
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
            if (spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        x = 1 / 1000;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        x = 1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        x = 1000;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        x = 1000000;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if (spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner2) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        y = 1 / 1000;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        y = 1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        y = 1000;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        y = 1000000;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Spinner and spinner2 have two arrays with mΩ,Ω,kΩ and MΩ and x,y are used to calculate something. The result of the calculation(Float sum = ((secondNumber*y) / ((secondNumber*y) + (firstNumber*x))) * thirdNumber;) is always 0. The calculation worked with one spinner. I am fairly new to java and would like a little bit of help.
thanks

Comment: You have not set listener to spinner 2. Please set it and check

Comment: I tried adding: spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()                                        ,but I had problems with the structure.

Comment: Hey @nurofen I still do not get your problem is it because you get 0 or you can not setOnItemSelecteListener??? What is your problem?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The program worked fine with one spinner. When i added the second one it didn't ie i got 0. So there must be an issue with the code. Jaymin suggested that i did not set listener to spinner2 but i don't know how to do that ...

Comment: As @Jaymin pointed you are setting the adapter code to spinner. The if part for spinner2 will never execute, you might as well remove it and directly set it when setting the adapter for spinner2.

Comment: You completely lost me there.. how do I also set the adapter code to spinner2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

Implement Lister in activity and while setting up listener pass **this**.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.om,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource
            (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.om2,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource
            (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

    // set spinner listener

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int
        position, long id) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
    if (spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                x = 1 / 1000;
                break;
            case 1:
                x = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                x = 1000;
                break;
            case 3:
                x = 1000000;
                break;
        }
    } else if (spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner2) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                y = 1 / 1000;
                break;
            case 1:
                y = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                y = 1000;
                break;
            case 3:
                y = 1000000;
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
}
```